# just can't build up the network connection

Tags: 20.04, system-installation

I tried to move to UBUNTU-server 20.04 from Win10. During the installation, I can't find the network `enp0s3` as the instruction. All I have is `Create bond` and `Continue without network`, and I have no idea about how to set the bond.

[image]

I keep moving till the end.  with lshw, I can see the ethernet card, but it is at `UNCLAIMED` status. Since I have no internet access, I can't get any tool with `apt-get`, like `ifconfig` or `NetworkManager`. The ethernet card is there for sure, I can access to the Internet if I install Windows 10.

Please help.

p.s. I think it is the driver issue. Since my MB is gigabyte b560m d3h, I asked gigabyte, they just don't know how to do with ubuntu.